# Get query string form $location.search() object / Call internal Angular method

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, `$location.search()` returns an object, which is handy to modify: add new params, alter or remove (set to `null`) existing ones. And `$location.search(object)` sets this object to the `search` component of `$location`. I'm looking for a way to get the composed query string from this object leaving the `$location` intact. I don't need to get the actual query string, I need to *compose* the query string from an object.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write a javascript function that transforms an object to the string of &-separated key-value pairs, Angular already has one. Basically what I'd like to do is to use [`toKeyValue`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1300) method from [Angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js), which is used to compose query string in the [`$$compose`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L126) function in [location.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js). However, it seems like `toKeyValue` method is inaccessible from outside Angular (unlike, for example, [`forEach`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L256)), as I'm getting `angular.toKeyValue is not a function` error when trying to call it. Is there any way to call `toKeyValue` method from my controller or just compose the query string from an object by means of Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$httpParamSerializer`  that converts objects to strings.

This will do from your controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $httpParamSerializer) {
  var querystring = $httpParamSerializer({ width:1680, height:1050 }); //height=1050&width=1680
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found it myself in [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3213#issuecomment-130248753) and even tried it two seconds before this answer.